# What is the total distance travel be abdula h in this trip

Tags: real-analysis

Saye and Abdulah walk at 4 miles per hour, and Maliaka drives 40 miles per hour. They set out from Fendall to Paynesville with Saye walking, and Abdulah riding with Maliaka. After an hour, Abdulah gets out of the car and starts walking to Paynesville, while Maliaka turns the car around and drives back to pick up Saye. When the car gets back to Saye, Saye gets into the car, the car turns around and drives until it meets Abdulah. How many total miles has Abdulah traveled when the car meets him?
You may assume that no time is required to turn around or to change passengers.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour, car has gone 40 miles and Saye has gone 4 miles.  So the car and Saye are 36 miles apart.  As the car drives back toward Saye (and Saye is walking toward the car), the distance between the car and Saye is diminishing at 44 mph.  Thus that distance is covered in $\frac{36}{44}=\frac9{11}$ of an hour.

While the car is driving toward Saye, and both Saye and Abdulah are walking at the same speed, and in the same direction, the distance between them is staying constant at 36 miles.  Thus when the car meets Saye, it is 36 miles from Abdulah.  And once the car turns around, it will gain on Abdulah by 36 mph (since its speed is 40 mph and Abdulah's speed is 4 mph).  Thus it will take another hour for the car to reach Abdulah.

So Abdulah walks for $1 \frac9{11}=\frac{20}{11}$ hours, at a speed of 4 mph.  So his distance walked is $\frac{80}{11}=7 \frac{3}{11}$ miles.

Comment: can i get some one to explain this for me please